# display a random selection of list items and shuffle

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists

I have a script that shuffles a list. But what I would like is that it shuffles and makes a selection of 4 items. Like this:

- Saturday
- Tuesday
- Monday
- Friday

How can I do this?

```js
var ul = document.querySelector('#lister');
for (var i = ul.children.length; i >= 0; i--) {
    ul.appendChild(ul.children[Math.random() * i | 0]);
}
```

```html
<ul id="lister">
    <li>Sunday</li>
    <li>Monday</li>
    <li>Tuesday</li>
    <li>Wednesday</li>
    <li>Thursday</li>
    <li>Friday</li>
    <li>Saturday</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: maybe easier to have the days in a variable array first then add to the `<ul>`

Comment: @Mike is right, and after shuffling array, you just need to add specific number of array elements to list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use conditional logic?  If you already have the max, just remove the node rather than append it.

```js
var ul = document.querySelector('#lister');
var max = 4;

for (var i = ul.children.length; i >= 0; i--) {
    if(ul.children.length - i > max) {
        ul.removeChild(ul.children[i]);
    } else {
        ul.appendChild(ul.children[Math.random() * i | 0]);
    }
}
```

```html
<ul id="lister">
    <li>Sunday</li>
    <li>Monday</li>
    <li>Tuesday</li>
    <li>Wednesday</li>
    <li>Thursday</li>
    <li>Friday</li>
    <li>Saturday</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you @josephMarikle this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

I made this code basing on @Mike 's comment, but I think @Joseph Marike 's answer is also awesome. So as you can know now, there're bunch of ways, you choose :)

```js
var liList = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
var ul = document.querySelector('#ul');
var ix, ixLen, rand;

for(ix = 0, ixLen = 7; ix < ixLen; ix++){
  rand = Math.ceil(Math.random() * ixLen) - 1;
  ul.innerHTML += '<li>' + liList[rand] + '</li>';
  liList.splice(rand, 1);
  ixLen--;
}
```

```html
<ul id='ul'>

</ul>
```

Comment: You can make it better if you loop until 4 and remove `ixLen--`.  anyway this is a good answer +1